# Basic MySQL syntax error when trying to connect to server

Tags: mysql

I am doing my first steps at MySQL. 
I installed it, and checked that it is working by running the commands:

- `select user();`
- `select version();`
- `select now();`

now, I'm trying to connect to the server, using the command

```
mysql -u root -p;
```

but I get an error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p' at line 1

what is the problem? In your explanations, please note that I don't know what are 
concepts like 'PATH variables' or bin directory (I ran into those while looking for a solution online before posting here, no idea what they are - I just want to run some queries!)

Comment: `mysql -u root -p` is a command you run from your shell (terminal, command-prompt), but you're entering it into an already open mysql prompt. Type `quit<enter>` to leave the open mysql prompt.

Comment: entering this command to teminal is the first thing i have tried! but it just says " 'mysql is not recognized as internal or external command..." what should I do?